# .NET unit test run without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have build the unit test DDL on my machine and run on the another place without installing visual studio.

To do this, I install the NUnit command line and call the my unit test DLL, and it does not work.

In my C# code I only add the `[TestMethod]` attribute on my test method.

The below image shows how I call the NUnit on the command line:

[image]

Is there an issue in here, or is there any other way to do this?

Note: I use the [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) library in my project.

Comment: Version of Nunit and By not console are same? Are you able to run the tests from visual studio?

Comment: yes its working on VS

Comment: Are you sure you have NUnit unit tests? `TestMethod` looks like `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethodAttribute` and not NUnit's one...

Comment: @LittleDragon Use `[Test]` attribute instead of `[TestMethod]` for Nunit.

Answer (score 2):

The NUnit console runner is made to run NUnit tests, that is, tests that use the NUnit framework. Since you are using the `[TestMethod]` attribute, you are probably using Microsoft's test framework.

NUnit used to be delivered (version 2) as a single package, but with version 3 it is divided into several different packages. You will have to download and reference the NUnit framework and change your tests to use its attributes and assertions.